# cx_freeze build without system modules

Tags: python, cx-freeze, software-distribution

I want to use cx_freeze to bungle my modules in one file to distribute on Linux.
I am using distutils setup script

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

mine= ["my","own","modules"]

build_exe_options = {
    "packages":mine,
    "includes":mine,
    "excludes":["dbus","glib","gobject"],
    "copy_dependent_files":True,
    "append_script_to_exe":True,
    "create_shared_zip":False,
}

base = "ConsoleKeepPath"

setup(  name = "project-eri",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "project-eri",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [
             Executable("project-eri.py", initScript=base, base=base, appendScriptToExe=True)
                      ]
     )
```

It works fine, but it copy modules from `/usr/lib/python2.7` and from site `site-packages`.
I do not want to rebuild and send binary to user each time site library updated.
I want to keep it updated with system updates. And i don`t want to write long "excludes".

Comment: You can use a `path` option to specify where it searches ([Docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe)). But if you know the user has a Python installation anyway, it's probably easier to just ship the .py files.

Comment: @ThomasK path trick did not work because of ImportError: No module named 'traceback'

Comment: Is that an error during freezing, or when running the frozen executable? Freezing might assume that it can find the standard library modules.

Comment: @ThomasK during freezing

Comment: maybe i can do it manualy: zip my code and attach to cx_freeze elf base.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it might take some digging in the cx_Freeze codebase to see how to arrange things.